# Enabling a field in input page based on a picklist value

Tags: visualforce, javascript

VF page to enable one of two fields based on picklist value in the same page. Please verify my code whether is right or worng. I am running this code but nothing happen.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changetextbox(){
            var ele=document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.block1.populate}');
            var opt=ele.options[ele.selectedIndex];
            if (opt=='Prospect'){
                var newEle=document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.block1.textpop}');
                newEle.enabled=true;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form id="form1">
        <apex:pageBlock id="block1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Type}" id="populate" onchange="changetextbox();"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.accountnumber}" id="textpop"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error here is that you must specify what parameter of the selected option you want  to get: `value` or `text`

For example the selected option looks like:

```
<option value="1">My Option</option>
```

To get the text `My Option` you need the following code:

```
var opt = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text;
```

And to get a value `1`:

```
var opt = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].value;
```

But what surprises me in your code is that you try to enable the output field. The output field is just a text block und could not be enabled?

Comment: thanks for reply Sergey . i had modify a code but nothing happen

Comment: @Udaya Sorry, i gave the wrong answer (simply overlooked :) Updated my code.